# Changing tabs on Tab Based Application Pushes UI Elements Down

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tabbed based iOS application. The fourth tab is linked to a UINavigationController. When I navigate to the home tab from the fourth tab, the UI elements of the home tab are pushed down. However, if I rotate the phone to landscape and then back to portrait, everything has moved up and is in the correct place.

In Storyboard, I set the top bar to `none`. I have the `UINavigationBar` hidden in the fourth tab/view controller before I navigate to the home tab.

Why would it be that the rotation fixes the constraints? How can I fix the UI elements such that they are not pushed down in the first place?

Here is a screen shot of my storyboard:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't really make sense. A 4th tab would not be embedded in a navigation controller. Instead, the 4th tab would link to a navigation controller. When you first select that tab you'd see the root view controller and it's navigation bar item. If you pushed a new view controller it would get pushed onto the navigation controller in tab 4. If you switch to one of the other tabs then the navigation controller will be swapped away and it's navigation bar will no longer be visible. Swap back to tab 4 you'll see it again, complete with it's navigation bar.

I created a sample app in order to confirm what I'm describing, as I haven't used tab bar controllers a lot, and not in quite a while I can upload the project if you really need to see it. It only contains a couple of lines of code (to implement the button on the navigation controller's view controller that creates and pushes a new view controller.)

Comment: I updated my question with a screenshot of my Storyboard. Though you are right - the 4th tab is linked to a navigation controller. I've updated my post with your correct language. But do you know why navigating from Snap It Nav controller to the home controller (here with the title Leafsnap) would push down the UI elements? And why rotating it would fix it?

Comment: How are you navigating from the navigation controller to the "leafsnap" view controller? By switching tabs?

Comment: Yes, I navigate by switching tabs. Nav Controller is third tab, and "leafsnap" vc is first tab.